# Is there any font which provides italic fraktur letters?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Is there any font which provides italic fraktur letters? I know that traditionally fraktur letters are upright. If I want to denote an arbitrary Lie algebra, then since it is a variable, it should be italic, right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Standard Fraktur is commonly used and the distinction between “variable=italic” and “constant=upright” is used in technical fields and experimental physics (as opposed to theoretical physics). Not commonly in pure math. And there's no such thing as “italic Fraktur”.

Comment: I'll second @egreg's comment that "there's no such thing as 'italic Fraktur'."

Comment: That's not entirely true. I don't see the need for it, and I don't think you should use them, but they certainly exist: https://www.fraktur.com/c/schriften/frakturschriften-kursiv

Comment: @Ingmar Is this historically based?

Comment: @egreg My understanding is that the Gutenberg Bible used colored text for emphasis and many other German documents put foreign words in Antiqua type, rather than Italics.

Comment: That might have had mainly practical reasons, though. I understand that there were very few broken fonts in italic, because both the production as well as the typesetting was rather difficult and very laborious.

Comment: History is not always decisive. Upright Greek letters were traditionally used, but slanted lowercase, simply because that was what was available, but the standard you refer to (ISO 80000-2, I assume) tries to regularize this. However, I have never personally seen anyone use slanted Fraktur in mathematics. But I might well be unfamiliar with a field where this is common. If you know of one, I would be very interested to hear of it!

Comment: @Davislor Yes, I want to comply with that ISO standard, although it is not generally used in pure math or theoretical physics as egreg has commented. I haven't seen italic Fraktur letters used anywhere (I wasn't even aware of their existence before Ingmar commented), but I thought if the standard requires variables to be italic, then Fraktur letters should be italic as well.

Comment: I have consulted Seemann's “Handbuch der Schriftarten. Eine Zusammenstellung der Schriften der Schriftgießereien deutscher Zunge nach Gattungen geordnet” (Handbook of Typefaces. A Compilation of Fonts by Type Foundries of German Tongue, Ordered by Category), Leipzig 1926. 

After 30 pages of regular broken fonts, there are exactly 8 Cursive Fraktur fonts. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SycmW.png So yes, they did exist, but they were exceedingly rare. Probably no need for them today ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correspondence “variable ↔ italic” and “constant ↔ upright” is foreign to pure mathematics. It's been enforced in technical writing by a disputable ISO norm that has very little mathematical justification.

For instance, the fact that the speed of light is denoted by an italic letter is justified because the value can change due to increased accuracy in the measurement. As a mathematician, I consider this ridiculous: either the speed of light is a constant of nature or it isn't.

In addition, I've never seen italic Fraktur. I was made aware that some (modern) typefaces offer it, but I don't think this practice is historically based.

Besides, the distinction between variable and constant is very blurred in pure mathematics. Physicists call “vector” what should be a “vector field” (hence a function); for a mathematician, a vector is a given element of a vector space. Logicians distinguish between variables and constants, but these concepts are quite different from the physicists’.

Do you want italic Fraktur? Use `unicode-math`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfontface{\itfrak}{Latin Modern Math}[FakeSlant=0.2]

\begin{document}

$\symfrak{sl}(2)$ is a Lie algebra linked to $\mathrm{SL}(2)$.

$\itfrakit{}$ is a generic Lie algebra.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use the fake slant method in a different context. Why is it that we need the unicode character inside the brackets? `\mathcal{g}` does not work.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Sorry, but I can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am saying that if I replace `\itfrak{}` with `\itfrak{\symfrak{g}}`, then it doesn't work. I don't understand why.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Is it *supposed* to work? Sorry, no.